# How to execute SELECT * LIKE statement with a placeholder in sqlite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've got an argument `tag` and I perfomed this way:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags LIKE '%?%'", (tag,))
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
 I'm new to sqlite, please tell me how to fix it. Thx !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apply the wildcards to the parameter, not the SQL:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags LIKE ?", (f'%{tag}%',))
```

The `?` SQL parameter interpolation adds quoting for you, so your query ends up as `'%'value'%'`, which is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `%`:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags LIKE ?", (tag,))
```

This should format it as you wanted. For example, if `tag == 'test'` the full query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags LIKE 'test'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wish to select any record that has `tag` in it, instead of `== tag` only. :-)

Comment: Ah.. I see what you meant. Missed it. :)