# python sqlite3 partial search

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, search

I want to do a partial search with `python` `sqlite3`. My initial query is:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?", (title, author, year, isbn))
```

Then I tried using the `LIKE` keyword and string formatting to obtain partial search results for the `title`, like this:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title LIKE ? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?", ('%{}%'.format(title), author, year, isbn))
```

As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20904256/13290801

This seems to do the trick for `title`, but now when searching on the other parameters, it's not working at all although there is no error on the terminal. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I tried the answer posted by @forpas, but it gives me the same results.

So my new code for my search function is:

```
def search(title="", author="", year="", isbn=""):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('books.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title LIKE '%' || ? || '%' OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?", (title, author, year, isbn))
```

It works for title. If I search for "amst", I get the Amsterdam title:
[image: Title partial search works]

But if I search by year for 1970 I get all the results:
[image: Year search doesn't work]

Comment: What do you want to list whenever the first text value is amst, and the second is 1970 at the same time ? I mean, do you want to return two lines or none.

Comment: That has to yield no lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do partial search for the title then you must concatenate the `'%'` wildcard at the start and at the end of the title that you search.
Also you need an additional condition for the case that you pass an empty string for a column and the operator `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
sql = """
SELECT * FROM book 
WHERE (title LIKE '%' || ? || '%' OR LENGTH(?) = 0)
  AND (author = ? OR LENGTH(?) = 0) 
  AND (year = ? OR LENGTH(?) = 0) 
  AND (isbn = ? OR LENGTH(?) = 0)
"""
cur.execute(sql, (title, title, author, author, year, year, isbn, isbn))
```

Comment: I get the same result as with my original code, i.e. the partial search for title works, but the (full) search for the others no longer work.

Comment: @MeL can you post sample data where my code does not work?

Comment: I've added the new code and some screenshots

Comment: @MeL you forgot to mention that you may search with empty strings for some of the parameters.

Comment: right, sorry! So is there no way to make it work like this?

Comment: This gives me the following error: `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 8, and there are 4 supplied.`

Comment: In my code there are 8 parameters passed in `cur.execute`. 2 for each column. Did you use the code as it is?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parameter list to append the non-null values for text boxes for `title`,`author`,`year`, and `isbn`(*trimming the complete whitespace values*), while adding counterparts of those parameters with use of `AND` rather than `OR` operator to the Select Statement such as

```
query = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE 1=1 "

prm=[]

if len(title.strip())>0:
    prm.append('%{}%'.format(title))
    query+=" AND title LIKE ?"

if len(author.strip())>0:
    prm.append(author)
    query+=" AND author=?"

if len(year.strip())>0:
    prm.append(year)
    query+=" AND year=?"

if len(isbn.strip())>0:
    prm.append(isbn)
    query+=" AND isbn=?"
    
cur.execute(query, (prm))
```

Comment: When 2 or more Textboxes are not empty in the form, then `OR` will not work. For example if Author = 'xyz' and Year = 1970, the results should be the books of 'xyz' in 1970.

Comment: By default, the SQLite LIKE operator is case-insensitive for ASCII chars.